# URI /ProjectTrackerMain/milestone/save Class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Message Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

When I'm trying to save data first entry save but when i trying for second entry
it gives error,this is error

> URI :/ProjectTrackerMain/milestone/save Class
>   :java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Message :Index: 0, Size: 0

this is my code for save the milestone data of employee.

```
def save(){
    def milestone=new Milestone(params)
    milestone.save()
    List<Employee> 
    employee=Employee.findAllById(session.getAttribute("empID"))
    EmployeeMilestone employeeMilestone=new EmployeeMilestone()
    employeeMilestone.setEmployee(employee.get(0))
    employeeMilestone.setMilestone(milestone)
    employeeMilestone.save()
    redirect(action: "show",id: employeeMilestone.id)
}
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095609/about-saving-data-into-grails-databse which you already accepted an answer on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About saving data into grails databse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095609/about-saving-data-into-grails-databse)

Comment: Formated text properly

Answer (score 0):

`employee.get(0)` - in order to do that, you must be sure that `employee.size() >=1`
but it is possible that your employee list is emply. in such case you cannot get element#0

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with the snippet of code, I will try to help you understand how to put all of above in a much better way, writing things in a confusing way isn't going to make it easier for you to debug:

```
// You are createing a list in which you query Employee.findAll
List<Employee>  employee=Employee.findAllById(session.getAttribute("empID"))

//But inside this list you are only looking for that 1 id.
```

Your above list will always contain 1 element. You are using findById which is really not needed if you know the id you can just do

```
Employee.get(session.getAttribute("empID") as Long)

//You are then creating employeeMilestone 
    EmployeeMilestone employeeMilestone=new EmployeeMilestone()
//Then without checking your 1 list result you are directly attempting to get the first element
    employeeMilestone.setEmployee(employee.get(0))
```

So lets try that again:

```
def save(){
    def milestone=new Milestone(params)
    milestone.save()
    //Do you even have something in your session?
    if (session.getAttribute("empID")) {
        println "yes we have ${session.getAttribute("empID")}"
        Employee employee=Employee.get(session.getAttribute("empID") as Long)
       if (employee) { 
         println "yes we have eployee ${employee?.id}
         EmployeeMilestone employeeMilestone=new EmployeeMilestone()
         employeeMilestone.employee=eployee
         employeeMilestone.milestone=milestone
         employeeMilestone.save()
         redirect(action: "show",id: employeeMilestone.id)
       } else {
         println "No employee found"
       }
     } else {
        println "session could not be found"
     }
}
```

Hope this doesn't make it to a 4th attempt of you asking something that obviously it is taking a long time to sink in

The fact you have redirect code in the actions suggests you are doing all of the above in a controller which is even further wrong turns.

Do transactional stuff in a service do controller stuff in a controller and do view stuff in view.